Windows tool that verifies the version of apps or drivers that are present on a machine?
We have non domain connected Windows 11 machines, and I am looking for software that can:

Tell us if given apps are installed, with minimum version.

Tell us if specified device drivers are installed, with minimum version.


If such a thing does not exist, we plan to create one.
The problem we want to solve is to verify quickly and accurately when software on a machine is missing or too old.

PowerShell would be a light-weight method of retrieving all of this information from multiple computers at the same time, all the way down to exporting a file with the results (CSV, HTML, .txt, etc).

I dont think you are going to find anything that checks normal applications. Most are written with some sort of auto update anyway.
For drivers I use Drivereasy.  I use the free version, so you have to manually download and update. The paid version will do it automatically.  Note, I am not associated with it. It pops up tegularly with a list of drivers that are outdated with info on new ones.
Blurb from site

We make updating your drivers easy
Our software, Driver Easy, makes updating your Windows drivers easy.

